# resize a uipanel without changing its children's sizes?

Tags: matlab, resize, panel, children

suppose that I have created this panel and have modified sizes of the children to my favorable size.
[image]
Now I understand that there is some spare space at the bottom of the panel and since I have little space for other panels, I decide to cut this spare space.
But whenever I do all of the children get smaller and thiner!
I know that I can change size of the panel and then resize its children to my favorable size. But is there an easier way in order to not wasting time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using GUIDE.

This is related to resize behaviour. If you follow Tools-> GUI Options you can see the combobox for resize behaviour. Yours is probably set to "Proportional".

If you change it to "Non-resizable", you will be able to resize your panel without affecting children sizes. You can change it back to "Proportional" after you are done.